# Query to return number of members belonging to groups and those who dont in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL. I basically want just two numbers: number of members who belong to any number of groups and those have no groups. Currently, I am using two queries to get first count of numbers who don't exist and then for those who have. But was hoping if there is a better way.

```
 members: id, name,gender
 groups: id,name
 member_groups:id,groupid,memberid
```

Currently I am doing:

```
 in_group=SELECT COUNT(id) FROM members WHERE id in (SELECT memberid FROM member_groups)

 not_in_group=SELECT COUNT(id) FROM members WHERE id not in (SELECT memberid FROM member_groups)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `SUM` and `CASE`.
`CASE` will return 1 when the member is in a group and 0 when it isn't, and `SUM` will get the total amount.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN id in (SELECT memberid FROM member_groups) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'in_group'
SUM(CASE WHEN id not in (SELECT memberid FROM member_groups) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'not_in_group'
FROM members
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a histogram of histograms approach:

```
select num_groups, count(*) as num_members_with_this_many_groups
from (select m.id, count(mg.id) as num_groups
      from members left join
           members_groups mg 
           on mg.id = m.memberid
      group by m.id
     ) m
group by num_groups;
```

The logic can easily be modified for 0 or more than 0 groups, but I usually find the listing of all the numbers as more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IN` clause to check whether a member is in a group, then count:

```
select is_in_a_group, count(*)
from
(
  select id in (select memberid from member_groups) as is_in_a_group
  from members m
) looked_up
group by is_in_a_group;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/IYY77021

Of course you can do exactly the same with an `EXISTS` clause instead. If the optimizer is good the execution plan will be the same.

This statement should be very fast, because with `IN` / `EXISTS` it suffices to find a member in only one group.